# changing a solution to a more efficient one

Tags: r, list, function

I have a code in R .. I really don't know what does it want to do, but It takes too long to execute and in my computer after a couple of hours it doesn't execute. would someone interpret the following code for me and also change it to a more efficient code ?

```
 Tempseq<-seq(0,30)
pCO2seq<-seq(0.04,10,by=0.05)

mas<- meshgrid(pCO2seq,Tempseq)
mapCO2<- mas[[1]]
maTemp<- mas[[2]]

resultdf<-CarboSolution(mapCO2[1],maTemp[2])

for(i in 2:length(mapCO2)){
  resultdf<-bind_rows(resultdf,CarboSolution(mapCO2[i],maTemp[i]))
}
```

Comment: What is the function `CarboSolution`. I think that is where the inefficiency is. I am assuming you are doing diffusion. In which case, that step might take the longest time.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what the functions `meshgrid` or `CarboSolution` do. Neither do I know from which package they are but growing objects in loop is highly inefficient. You can try `Map` in base R :

```
resultdf <- do.call(rbind, Map(CarboSolution, mapCO2, maTemp))
```

Or `purrr`'s `map2_df` :

```
resultdf <- purrr::map2_df(mapCO2, maTemp, CarboSolution)
```

Comment: meshgrid is from (pracma package) and CarboSolution  is a user defined function , Actually for me the last line of the mentioned command does not execute. 
for(i in 2:length(mapCO2)){
  resultdf<-bind_rows(resultdf,CarboSolution(mapCO2[i],maTemp[i]))
}

Comment: If you are using my answer you don't have to use `for` loop. Use one of the two options I provided above.

Comment: again I have the same problem.. I have executed your command but it has not finished yet.

Comment: I tried both of your command and I had the same problem

Answer (score 0):

We can do this with `data.table`

```
 library(data.table)
 rbindlist(Map(CarboSolution, mapCO2, maTemp))
```